# Magento Layered Navigation - Category links

Tags: magento

I have this site on magento, wherein on category pages there is browse by category filter in the left.

But the issue is the links are like www.domain.com/main-cat/?cat=32 because of which, the products sure gets pulled but the category description and image remains the same as that of the main category.

is there any way to convert these dynamic urls to /main-cat/sub-cat ?

magento varsion 1.4.2

Thanks & Regards,

Sushil

Comment: I find it weird too. There should be at least a correct canonical tag pointing to the main-car/sub-cat url.